# How Does This String Permutation Works

Tags: algorithm, recursion, permutation

Need help understanding the correctness of the second swap call.

```
/* Function to print permutations of string
   This function takes three parameters:
   1. String
   2. Starting index of the string
   3. Ending index of the string. */
void permute(char *a, int i, int n) 
{
   int j; 
   if (i == n)
     printf("%s\n", a);
   else
   {
       for (j = i; j <= n; j++)
       {
          swap((a+i), (a+j));
          permute(a, i+1, n);
          swap((a+i), (a+j)); // how does this work here?
       }
   }
}
```

It seems like the second swap is to undo the first swap. But I don't see a proof why the in-between `permute` call would preserve that the original `*(a+i)` would remain at `a+j`.

Notes:

[1] Code was found at http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-to-print-all-permutations-of-a-given-string/

Comment: Have you given this code a run through by hand?

Comment: Prove it by induction. It's obviously true for `i == n-1`. If it's true for some `0  < i`, then it's also true for `i-1`.

Comment: @BlackVegetable. I did something equivalent: adding printf. And it shows that indeed the `permute` call seems to preserve `a` before and after the call. Now, I just can't prove why.

Comment: @DanielFischer. It is the induction case that I'm having trouble. How do I know that second `swap` undo the first `swap` given that the in-between `permutate` may not preserve `a`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Proposition:** For all `a` of length `> n` (so that `n` is a valid index) and `0 <= i <= n`, when

```
permute(a, i, n)
```

returns, `a` is the same as when `permute` was called.

**Proof:** (Induction start) If `i == n`, then `permute(a, n, n);` only prints the string and doesn't change it, hence the proposition holds in that case.

(Induction hypothesis) Let `0 <= k < n`, and the enoncé of the proposition hold for all `k < i <= n`.

Then in the loop

```
for (j = i; j <= n; j++)
{
    swap((a+i), (a+j));
    permute(a, i+1, n);
    swap((a+i), (a+j)); // how does this work here?
}
```

for each `j`, the recursive call to `permute` doesn't change the contents [more precisely, it undoes all changes intermediately done] per the hypothesis. Therefore, before the second `swap`, the contents of `a[i]` and `a[j]` are exactly what they were after the first swap, hence at the end of the loop body, the contents of `a` are exactly what they were when the loop body was entered.